# Display the 3rd highest value of each week

Tags: excel

I have Data with a Price Column and a Week Column and I want to display the 3rd lowest price for each of those weeks. I know about the Large function and am assuming that there is a way to combine array formulas with that to receive the wanted results but am stuck on that thought.

Setup:

Week| Price

01   100

01    300

01    200

02    500

02    300

02    600

I want to automatically have the 3rd best price for each of those weeks available so Week 1 : 100 and Week 2: 300, keep in mind that each week has way more pricepoints than 3.

If anything is unclear feel free to ask.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: you should first decide what a week is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose your data would fill a table A1:B6.
In column C write the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$6=A1)*(B1<$B$1:$B$6))+1
```

This will rank all the values in column B based on the same value of column A. You will end up with the following table:

```
1   100 3
1   300 1
1   200 2
2   500 2
2   300 3
2   600 1
```

All you have to do is to take the rank=3.